# To find file in the directory using Timestamp of file

Tags: python, regex, pyspark

I have one directory which contains below files for example purpose.

> file:input/dir/input_data_Export_20190405121071.csv
>   file:input/dir/data_Export_20190406081001.csv 
>   file:input/dir/input_Export_20190406161241.csv
>   file:input/dir/raw_data_Export_20190407121041.csv
>   file:input/dir/input_data_Export_20190407101101.csv

Here how can I retrieve a file which starts with "*2019040712*" and it should have the latest timestamp using Python. For example **"input_data_Export_20190407101101.csv"** is the file I want to retrieve.

Comment: Are you trying to get this file on a spark cluster?

Comment: yes ,i am getting these file on pyspark cluster@cronoik

Comment: Are these files avaiable on all nodes? In case they are not avaiable on all nodes and you have more then one node, you can never be sure if your code is executed on the node which is holding these files. You should consider using hadoop as distributed file system.

Answer (score 0):

this code is giving you the name of the file with the latest timestamp. You must replace `[$YOUR_PATH]` by the path to the directory where your files are.

```
import glob

timestamp_temp = 0

for filename in glob.glob("[$YOUR_PATH]/input_data_Export_2019040712*.csv"):
    timestamp = filename[-18:-4] 
    if int(timestamp) > int(timestamp_temp):
        file=filename
        timestamp_temp=timestamp

print(file)
```